# I need a batch file that opens cmd, runs two commands, and keeps cmd open

Tags: command-line, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am making a set of batch files made to force restart games when they freeze and won't start back up again.

So I need a batch file that opens cmd.exe, runs the two commands:

```
taskkill /F example.exe`
```

and

```
start example.exe
```

and lets cmd stay open. Every time I try these two commands cmd is just open for a second and closes saying that no command was made, or the commands aren't able to be used even though they work when I type them into cmd directly.

Comment: I found out that I was encoding my batch files as unicode instead of ANSI but I wouldn't have known how to do these commands anyways if I didn't post this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I need a batch file that opens `cmd`, runs two commands, and keeps cmd open

```
taskkill /F example.exe
```

This is an invalid command. You need to use:

```
taskkill /F /IM example.exe
```

- `/IM image name`. The image name of the process to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used to specify all image names.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
taskkill /F /IM example.exe
start example.exe
endlocal
```

To run it and keep the `cmd` shell open use the following command:

```
cmd /k test
```

- `/K` Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt. This is useful for testing, to examine variables

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).
- [taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) - End one or more processes (by process id or image name).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pause` at the end to leave it open 'till you hit a button.